# Contaminated Ore and Mysterious Green Liquid

Tags: baldurs-gate

I got the impression from a not-quite-intentional quick glance at a spoiler that the mayor of Naskell was going to was going to ask me to deliver the samples to somebody. That didn't happen. The mayor thanked me, gave me 900 coins, took the holy symbol off my hands, then disappeared. I hate having unfinished business. I also hate wasting valuable inventory space. Is there something I'm supposed to do with these things? Or can I just drop them?

Comment: It has been an extremely long time since I played, but a cursory Google search says that the items are useless, but that there is a mod that adds in a couple of small quests with them.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I'd have done a Google search myself, but that's a good way to get spoilers you don't actually want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carrying the contaminated ore in your inventory makes non-magic metal weapons more likely to break. The Mysterious Green Liquid, when consumed, causes 1 point of constitution loss. In the standard version of the game, they have no other purpose. In the Enhanced Edition, ["Investigating Nashkel Mines simply disappears after completing Chapter 2."](http://baldursgate.wikia.com/wiki/The_tainted_ore)

Comment: Really? I've never heard that about the ore before.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't installed the mod "Unfinished Business" the items are indeed useless. With the mod installed you are supposed to take a sample of the ore to Taerom Fuiruim in Beregost and the mysterious liquid to Thalantyr in High Hedge. But this will only give you minor XP, you won't be able to stop the iron shortage this way.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! I'm not playing anymore right now, but I may pick it up again.